# Extracting zipped files using JSZIP in javascript

Tags: javascript, unzip, jszip

In my webpage, a user is supposed to upload a zipped file. Within the zipped file are 2 files: another zip file and a txt file. On my server, after receiving the zip, I want to unzip the zip file to extract the zip & txt file, then move those 2 files to a predefined folder. I have a piece of code that extracts the zip file, but the data doesn't seem correct. Firstly, it unzipped a zip and 2 txt file when there should only be 1 txt file. It created an additional 'undefined' txt file. Also, in my txt file, instead of the original data, it was replaced with the following text: '[undefined] [undefined]'. 
Can anyone help me on this? The following is my code:

```
var JSZip = require('JSZip');

fs.readFile( filePath, function(err, data){
  if (!err){
    var zip = new JSZip();
    JSZip.loadAsync(data).then(function(zip){
      object.keys(zip.files).forEach(function(filename){
        var content = zip.files[filename];
        var dest = path + filename;
        fs.writeFileSync(dest, content);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Is this code running in node? If so, you might want to add the tag for clarity.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It took a bit of digging in their documentation but they have [an example](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples.html) that shows how to read the file contents from a ZIP.

You are getting the object that *describes* the ZIP contents but not the actual content. Here is an adjusted version:

```
var JSZip = require('JSZip');

fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        var zip = new JSZip();
        zip.loadAsync(data).then(function(contents) {
            Object.keys(contents.files).forEach(function(filename) {
                zip.file(filename).async('nodebuffer').then(function(content) {
                    var dest = path + filename;
                    fs.writeFileSync(dest, content);
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I tried it out but its not even unzipping now. Have u tried it out? Is it working for u?

Comment: I think something went wrong with this line "zip.files(filename).async('nodebuffer').then(function(content) {". I did a print and the print doesnt show after this line.

Comment: .async('nodebuffer') seems to the the problem. I did a print using .async and it will get stuck there.

Comment: I have tried it and it works for me. Are you running this in node.js (if yes, what version) or in the browser?

Comment: To show errors (if any), add a `catch` callback on the promise: `.then(function(content) {...}).catch(function(e) {console.error(e)})`

Comment: Yes i am using node.js. My code is in my controller, which shouldnt be a problem either right? For some reason whenever i added .async it wont work..

Comment: Im using sails v0.12.3, and after adding the catch, it didnt cstch anything.

Comment: Here's the running sample plus the test.zip: http://code.runnable.com/V85uLPcBDC5wwPy7/jszip-unzip-example-for-node-js-and-hello-world

Comment: Oh dear it worked.. but instead of JSZip.loadAsync, i used zip.loadAsync

Comment: @QLiu - It's generally correct but there are a few issues with the code: `object` should be `Object`, `zip.files(filename)` should be `zip.files[filename]`. See my answer below which might help.

Comment: files must be an `ArrayBuffer`, which can also come from the browser; i.e. a web requests can return an ArrayBuffer (see `d3.buffer` in the `d3-fetch` module); and a browser file upload can parse a user's local file to an ArrayBuffer with the [File API](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples/read-local-file-api.html))

Answer (score 39):

This is a working version I am using:

```
var jsZip = require('jszip')
jsZip.loadAsync(file).then(function (zip) {
  Object.keys(zip.files).forEach(function (filename) {
    zip.files[filename].async('string').then(function (fileData) {
      console.log(fileData) // These are your file contents      
    })
  })
})
```

You can get most of the information you need from http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples.html but it's a little hard to get in one place, you have to look around a bit.

Comment: Strange to get a downvote after so long - is there something that needs changing?

Comment: @webnoob I don't know why you got the downvote, but ``.async('string')`` doesn't work for me with the latest version and I would prefer arrow functions here.

Comment: @YannicHamann you simply do `.async('text').then((fileContents) => { // do stuffs with file contents });`

Comment: What does the variable file contain here exactly?

Comment: @Karlsson It's a file from a HTML file selector i.e `e.target.files[0]` when listening for a change event on the form element.

Comment: On the 2nd line, is `file` the zip file? Please be clear, because in the next answer he reads the zip file content first with `fs.readFile()`

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira See my comment above yours. It's a user selected file from the HTML file selector. Essentially, it'll just be the binary data of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Here was my strategy in Angular 10 to write a single file to a zip with a custom extension, then later read that same zip to retrieve the json.

Package the file into a zip (custom file endings supported)

```js
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
import * as JSZip from 'jszip';

export async function exportJson(
  filename: string,
  jsonToExport: string,
  fileNameEnding = '.zip'
): Promise<string> {
  const jsonFile = new Blob([jsonToExport], {
    type: 'application/json',
  });

  if (!jsonFile) return Promise.reject('Error converting file to JSON');

  const zipper = new JSZip();
  zipper.file(`${filename}.json`, jsonFile);
  const zippedFile = await zipper.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' });

  const exportFilename = `${filename}${fileNameEnding}`;
  saveAs(zippedFile, exportFilename);
  return Promise.resolve(exportFilename);
}
```

Read the file contents from the zip

```js
// file parameter retrieved from an input type=file
export async function readExportedJson(file: File): Promise<Blob> {
  const zipper = new JSZip();
  const unzippedFiles = await zipper.loadAsync(file);
  return Promise.resolve(unzippedFiles).then(unzipped => {
    if (!Object.keys(unzipped.files).length) {
      return Promise.reject('No file was found');
    }
    return unzipped.files[Object.keys(unzipped.files)[0]];
  }).then(unzippedFile => zipper.file(unzippedFile.name).async('string'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is `cordova-plugin-file` specific.

As stated in the [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#browser-quirks):

> Directory entries have to be created successively. For example, the
>   call fs.root.getDirectory('dir1/dir2', {create:true}, successCallback,
>   errorCallback) will fail if dir1 did not exist.

I am almost certain that the currently accepted answer cannot guarantee that file content/folders are always retrieved in the same order. This could result in problems with an API such as `cordova-plugin-file`. Especially when you invoke another async function to asynchronously create the directory on the filesystem.

You may want to filter the directories of your zip archive first and create them in a sync manner before continuing to extract other files as already answered:

```
const directoryNames = Object.keys(zip.files).filter(name => zip.files[name].dir);
for (const directoryName of directoryNames) {
    await this.createDirectory(directoryName, dirEntry);
}
// ...

private createDirectory = (dirName: string, dirEntry: DirectoryEntry) => {
    const promise = new Promise<DirectoryEntry>(resolve, reject) => {
        dirEntry.getDirectory(dirName, { create: true }, dirEntry => {
            resolve(dirEntry);
        }, fileError => reject(fileError));
    });
    return promise;
}
```